# Replace default audio control with pavucontrol

Tags: 12.04, sound, volume-control, pavucontrol

Thanks to Ask Ubuntu, recently I discovered [PulseAudio Volume Control](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/) (pavucontrol) and started using it with joy.

My question is this: is there a way to use it in place of the default audio control shipped with Ubuntu 12.04? I would like to get pavucontrol to appear by clicking on the speaker icon in the Unity top bar.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible without editing the source code for the sound indicator.

Comment: Thanks! Any reference on that or at least a short explanation?

Comment: @Guandalino I'm not sure I can find a quick reference for you but essentially the sound indicator is hard coded to launch specific applications, and its options (in dconf) do not include the option to choose a volume control application of your own.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard coded in the source code, but the change is quite simple.

There is, however, a ready-made package that can be found here:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/sound1
$ sudo aptitude update
$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

The *indicator-sound* will be upgraded.

EDIT: According to [Launchpad bug #961745](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/961745), *xfce4-mixer* was replaced by *pavucontrol* on Xubuntu since *indicator-sound* version *0.8.4.1-0ubuntu4*